# How to use Automapper to project object to Dto in LINQ

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core, automapper

I am working on .NET Core 6 along with EF Core. I want to convert `Customer` and `Order` object that I have inside LINQ `select` to `CustomerDto` and `OrderDto` using `ProjectTo`.

Using libraries

```
using AutoMapper;
using AutoMapper.QueryableExtensions;
```

I am aware how to map `IQueryable` using the code shown here:

```
var x = (from customer in db.Customers
         where customer.CustomerId == CustomerId
         select customer).ProjectTo<CustomerDto>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider);
```

but I'm not sure how to project inside new or if it should be done differently? Below is LINQ code that I want customer to `CustomerDto` & `Order` to `OrderDto`

```
var customerOrdersQuery =
            (from customer in db.Customers.Where(x => x.CustomerId == CustomerId)
             join orders in db.Orders on customer.CustomerId equals orders.CustomerId into cst_Ord
             from customerOrders in cst_Ord.DefaultIfEmpty()
             select new { 
                 customer,        //ProjectTo<CustomerDto>
                 customerOrders   //ProjectTo<OrderDto>
             }).AsEnumerable();
```

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Queryable-Extensions.html

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu tried re-reading the docs but cannot see how anonymous types could be the source for projections? would be handy, I've always created dummy source classes to solve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Afaik you need an intermediary class CustomerWithOrdersSource which you map to CustomerWithOrdersDto, using Automapper's ProjectTo.

Mapping

```cs
public class CustomerWithOrdersSource
{
   public Customer Customer {get;set;}
   public ICollection<Order> Orders {get;set;}
}
public class CustomerWithOrdersDto
{
   public CustomerDto Customer {get;set;}
   public ICollection<OrderDto> Orders {get;set;}
}
CreateMap<CustomerWithOrdersSource, CustomerWithOrdersDto>();
```

Query

```cs
var customerOrdersQuery =
            (from customer in db.Customers.Where(x => x.CustomerId == CustomerId)
             join orders in db.Orders on customer.CustomerId equals orders.CustomerId into cst_Ord
             from customerOrders in cst_Ord.DefaultIfEmpty()
             select new CustomerWithOrdersSource() { 
                 Customer = customer,
                 Orders = customerOrders
             }).ProjectTo<CustomerWithOrdersDto>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider);
```

Edit: According to @Lucian Bargaoanu you can project directly from anonymous object as well. But this way you could easily customize the mapping by editing the mapping profile, if necessary later on.

Comment: You can project directly to `CustomerWithOrdersDto`. And you don't need the linq query when you add FK object properties.